# How to find a regex in PDFminer in python?

Tags: python, regex, pdf, pdfminer

I have a code to find a specific regex in my PDF and print the occurrences, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO
import re

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path="fel.pdf"):
    regex = re.compile(r"\[(\s)prima(?!\S)")

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    for x in text:
        match = re.findall(r"\[\s*prima(?!\S)", text)
        print(match)


print(convert_pdf_to_txt("fel.pdf"))
```

regex is "[ prima "

what isn't working?

Comment: Did you try `match = re.findall(r"\[\s*prima(?!\S)", x)` instead?

Comment: I just tried, but it seems it doesn't read the whole file (1300+ pages) so there are very few matches...

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the software, but it seems you are getting the pages and perhaps you have to add your logic inside that for loop to process each page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding regex in PDF with PDFminer (python) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833189/finding-regex-in-pdf-with-pdfminer-python-not-working)