# Finding regex in PDF with PDFminer (python) not working

Tags: python, regex, pdf, findall, pdfminer

I'm trying to find occurrences of a regular expression in a short pdf. However, it doesn't work. I don't understand why, because if I try to search a simple string I don't have problems. The text is rendered correctly. Here is my code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO
import re

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    #\[\s*prima(?!\S)regex = re.compile(r"\[(\s)prima(?!\S)")

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    reg = re.compile(r"\[(\s)prima(?!\S)")
    matches = re.findall(reg, text)
    return matches


print(convert_pdf_to_txt("fel_split.pdf"))
```

This is my regex: `(r"\[(\s)prima(?!\S)")`
I want to find "[ prima ".

Comment: Then use `r"\[\sprima\s"` or `r"\[\s*prima\s*"` or `r"\[\s+prima\s+"`

Comment: Do you really need a capturing group `(\s)`? What are you interested in? The `prima` part?

Comment: I'm interested in the square bracket + space + "prima" + another space. Unfortunately none of Wiktor Stribizew solution worked...

Comment: @Anna can you share a .pdf with no sensitive info, but on which this could be reproduced?

Comment: Try `"(?s)\[.*?prima` and if it does not work, there is no `[` followed with `prima` in your input text.

Comment: sure, this is the pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFlw1jlLzJ-5HiE2IUoiQPSUtuKb9uEo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Another bracket should be used, no? `]` instead of `[`

Comment: no, it's just `[` I know it's weird

Comment: it's "prima", without the s

Comment: if I search "[" it returns more though

Comment: Ok, so there is no `[ prima` in your document. You can't find something with regex that is not in the text

Comment: you're right, I had the wrong bracket.... sorry! it was ]....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are more than one space char? Try this: `r"\]\s*prima\b"`

**UPD:** and as it appears from the sample document another bracket should've been used: `]` instead of `[`.

Comment: Actually there could be more than one space, even if it's unusual... but it doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: This one maybe: `r"\[.*prima(?!\S)"`. In case those are not space chars somehow